# Update the DOM using One AJAX Call in WordPress

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress

I update vote count on the content of a post, but I also have a widget that has counts of votes on each post. When the user clicks on the vote on a post, the vote counts
in each post of the widget does not get updated.

I wrote an AJAX function that calls function through actions like so

// AJAX function file ajax-vote-on-post.js

```
function voteOnPost(postId) {
jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: voteonpostajax.ajaxurl,
    data: {
        action: 'addvote-to-post',
        postid: postId
    },

    success: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {

        var votecontainerid = '#vote-count-' + postId;
        jQuery(votecontainerid).html('');
        jQuery(votecontainerid).append(data);

    },
    error: function(MLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(errorThrown);
    }
});
```

}

I properly registered the ajax file to be called by WP in a *Widget file* that contains other functions and PHP codes.

...
// function in the PHP file that is called.

```
 function addvote-to-post(){
   $result = '';
   // get vote count from DB
   $post_ID = $_POST['postid'];
   $votepostcount = get_post_meta($post_ID, '_votepostcount', true) != '' ? get_post_meta($post_ID, '_votepostcount', true) : '0';

   // Code that updates the DB in WordPress does other things
     ...
   // Output count on the DOM
   $votecountnew = $votepostcount + 1;

   $result = '<div class="vote-count-'.$post_ID.'" >'.$votepostcountNew.'</div>'
   
   // update_all_count_for_post($post_ID, $votecountnew);
   

   die($result);


 }
```

The page load slowly and how best to update the DOM without using an extra function.

```
class MyVotePostWidget extends WP_Widget {
   // Widget Front End
   public function widget {
     // HTML code to display posts with votes
     
   }
}
```

Comment: the var votecontainerid start with # ? or maybe need jquery("#"+votecontainerid) ?

Comment: @toto, I am using jQuery for the AJAX call.